# How to Split a JSON string to two JSON objects in Java

Tags: java, json, org.json

I have a `JSON` object as follows:

```
{  
   "token":"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9",
   "user":{  
      "pk":17,
      "username":"user1",
      "email":"user1@gmail.com",
      "first_name":"",
      "last_name":""
   }
}
```

I am trying to get two `JSON` object from it; token and user. I have tried two different ways but both are failing:

```
//response.body().string() is the above json object
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response.body().string());

jsonObjectRoot = new JSONObject(response.body().string());
```

Could any one please let me know how I could split this to two `JSON` objects?

Comment: Which language are you using? JavaScript or Java?

Comment: Its in Java in Android Studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split it this way:

```
// source object
JSONObject sourceObject = new JSONObject(sourceJson);

String tokenKey = "token";
// create new object for token
JSONObject tokenObject = new JSONObject();

// transplant token to new object
tokenObject.append(tokenKey, sourceObject.remove(tokenKey));
// if append method does not exist use put
// tokenObject.put(tokenKey, sourceObject.remove(tokenKey));

System.out.println("Token object => " + tokenObject);
System.out.println("User object => " + sourceObject);
```

Above code prints:

```
Token object => {"token":["eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9"]}
User object => {"user":{"last_name":"","pk":17,"first_name":"","email":"user1@gmail.com","username":"user1"}}
```

Comment: looks like append is not resolving in tokenObject.append

Comment: @NabatFarsi, what library do you use and in which version? Don't you use [`org.json`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json/20180813)

Comment: its built in library in Android studio,

Comment: @NabatFarsi, I guess it is `org.json`. Can you at least show imports for `JSONObject` and `JSONArray` classes?

Comment: you are right it is org.Json, so likely it is different version, I'll take further look into it

Comment: @NabatFarsi, in that case you should use `put` method: `tokenObject.put(tokenKey, sourceObject.remove(tokenKey));`. Check updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse a json string with

```
var obj = JSON.parse(jsonString);
```

You can filter sub parts of a json object by simply addressing them

```
var token = obj.token;
var user = obj.user;
```

Comment: I don't think it is Java?Is it?

Comment: It's not. This would be the Javascript side of the solution, which is not what you were looking for. ;)

Answer (score 0):

The safer / cleaner way to do it is to create a POJO and deserialize your JSON into it using Jackson. Your pojo:

```
public class MyObject {
    String token;
    User user;

    static class User {
        int pk;
        String username;
        String email;
        String first_name;
        String last_name;
    }
}
```

Then, when you want to deserialize:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
```

and

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
MyObject myObject = mapper.readValue(jsonString, MyObject.class);
String token = myObject.token;
User user = myObject.user;
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently faced the same situation, I used the below code which worked for me:

```
    JSONObject jo1 = new JSONObject(output);

    JSONObject tokenObject = new JSONObject();
    tokenObject.put("token", jo1.get("token"));
    JSONObject userObject = new JSONObject();
    userObject.put("user", jo1.get("user"));
```

Here I am creating a new empty JSONObject and then put the retrieved object from the original object in the newly created JSONObject.

You can also verify the output by just sysout:

```
    System.out.println("token:" + tokenObject.get("token"));
    System.out.println("user:" + userObject.get("user"));
```

Output in my case :

```
token::eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9
user:{"last_name":"","pk":17,"first_name":"","email":"user1@gmail.com","username":"user1"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yep. It is a JSON string.
Using like this

```
JSONParser jparse=new JSONParser();
JSONObject jObj=(JSONObject)jParse.parse(jsonString);
```

jObj will contain json Object now.